# google scholar switching my first and last name

Tags: google-scholar, personal-name

Google scholar switches my first and last name although the journals publish my name correctly. And now due to people downloading citations from Google Scholar, other journals are also citing my first name as last name. How do I fix this? It is very frustrating.

Comment: Is your name in Western order, that is [given name] [family name]?

Comment: I'm confused and I try to do the right thing. My interpretation of your name given how you sign in here is that Yi is your family name and Soojin is your given name (since it has more than one syllable). If that is wrong then others are confused as well. I don't use Google Scholar, but suspect that for indexing purposes they need to use your family name and got it wrong. They probably have an algorithm that says "(Asia or Hungary) therefore swap names", though a bit more sophisticated but still incorrect.

Comment: @Buffy that would be really weird, I would expect Google Scholar and the like to simply use the name in whatever form it appears in the original publication.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, except for the indexing problem. The don't want to index by personal name. If someone "westernizes" their name and someone else doesn't realize they have, it can get confusing. A problem with bots in general since they just assume stuff.

Comment: @Buffy But the alternative of "swapping" names you suggest seems a lot worse due to the possibility of false positives, using what the author gives at least gives them full control on how they want their name to be indexed. At least in the submission systems I have used, I've only ever been asked for first name, last name, and perhaps a middle initial, there never was any mention of given or family names.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, you are starting to see the problem."First name" for a Hungarian is the family name. The terminology is insufficiently accurate. Thats why I used family name and personal (given) name. I'm aware of the issue but need to look up "surname" on occasion (old brain).

Comment: My first (given ) name is Soojin and my last (family) name is Yi, and I have a middle initial V. All the original journal publications have my name listed correctly. For some reason Google Scholar often indexes me as VY Soojin, as if VY is my first name and Soojin is my last name.

Comment: Well that's certainly weird then. Are these articles originally published in English?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him, yes.

Comment: Curious, if [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/108/14/5679.short) is yours, Google gives it as "VY Soojin" but it imports to BibTeX just fine. I'm not really sure, sorry

Comment: Thank you - I think for some other papers, the import option switches the first and last. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Google Scholar profile with your correct name, you can claim authorship of articles. Google Scholar results will then list your name correctly when the article is returned in searches. If you still have a problem after you have a profile and have claimed your articles, you can ask Google Scholar support for help.